# Change XML output recursively based on other content of same XML

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BMECAT version="1.2">
    <T_NEW_CATALOG>
        <CATALOG_GROUP_SYSTEM>
            <CATALOG_STRUCTURE type="root">
                <GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
                <PARENT_ID>0</PARENT_ID>
            </CATALOG_STRUCTURE>
            <CATALOG_STRUCTURE type="node">
                <GROUP_ID>2</GROUP_ID>
                <PARENT_ID>1</PARENT_ID>
            </CATALOG_STRUCTURE>
            <CATALOG_STRUCTURE type="node">
                <GROUP_ID>3</GROUP_ID>
                <PARENT_ID>1</PARENT_ID>
            </CATALOG_STRUCTURE>
            <CATALOG_STRUCTURE type="leaf">
                <GROUP_ID>4</GROUP_ID>
                <PARENT_ID>2</PARENT_ID>
            </CATALOG_STRUCTURE>
            <CATALOG_STRUCTURE type="leaf">
                <GROUP_ID>5</GROUP_ID>
                <PARENT_ID>3</PARENT_ID>
            </CATALOG_STRUCTURE>
        </CATALOG_GROUP_SYSTEM>
        <ARTICLE_TO_CATALOGGROUP_MAP>
            <ART_ID>ART1</ART_ID>
            <CATALOG_GROUP_ID>5</CATALOG_GROUP_ID>
        </ARTICLE_TO_CATALOGGROUP_MAP>
    </T_NEW_CATALOG>
</BMECAT>
```

I need to set an attribute `inUse=true` to `CATALOG_STRUCTURE`s (and the element they reference in their `PARENT_ID` element) that are referenced in any of the `ARTICLE_TO_CATALOGGROUP_MAP/CATALOG_GROUP_ID` elements.

I cannot quite wrap my head around how I could manipulate part of the document based on what is written in another part of the document, especially if that part is basically a tree but is displayed flattened.

Starting off I created this, but got stuck on writing the `markGroup` template...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="isUsed">
        <xsl:param name="groupId" />
        <xsl:if test="//CATALOG_GROUP_ID/text() = $groupId">true</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CATALOG_STRUCTURE">
        <xsl:variable name="groupId" select="GROUP_ID/text()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="isUsedDirectly">
            <xsl:call-template name="isUsed">
                <xsl:with-param name="groupId" select="$groupId"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="CATALOG_STRUCTURE">
            <xsl:if test="$isUsedDirectly = 'true'">
                <xsl:attribute name="inUse">true</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this only selects the "direct" groups, and doesn't mark the parents as used as it should.

The desired output for this example would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BMECAT version="1.2">
    <T_NEW_CATALOG>
        <CATALOG_GROUP_SYSTEM>
            <CATALOG_STRUCTURE type="root" inUse="true">
                <GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
                <PARENT_ID>0</PARENT_ID>
            </CATALOG_STRUCTURE>
            <CATALOG_STRUCTURE type="node">
                <GROUP_ID>2</GROUP_ID>
                <PARENT_ID>1</PARENT_ID>
            </CATALOG_STRUCTURE>
            <CATALOG_STRUCTURE type="node" inUse="true">
                <GROUP_ID>3</GROUP_ID>
                <PARENT_ID>1</PARENT_ID>
            </CATALOG_STRUCTURE>
            <CATALOG_STRUCTURE type="leaf">
                <GROUP_ID>4</GROUP_ID>
                <PARENT_ID>2</PARENT_ID>
            </CATALOG_STRUCTURE>
            <CATALOG_STRUCTURE type="leaf" inUse="true">
                <GROUP_ID>5</GROUP_ID>
                <PARENT_ID>3</PARENT_ID>
            </CATALOG_STRUCTURE>
        </CATALOG_GROUP_SYSTEM>
        <ARTICLE_TO_CATALOGGROUP_MAP>
            <ART_ID>ART1</ART_ID>
            <CATALOG_GROUP_ID>5</CATALOG_GROUP_ID>
        </ARTICLE_TO_CATALOGGROUP_MAP>
    </T_NEW_CATALOG>
</BMECAT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a key and a recursive function to traverse the references:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="CATALOG_STRUCTURE" use="GROUP_ID"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:get-refs" as="element(CATALOG_STRUCTURE)*">
        <xsl:param name="ids" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="refs" as="element(CATALOG_STRUCTURE)*" select="key('ref', $ids, $catalog)"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$refs, if (exists($refs)) then mf:get-refs($refs/PARENT_ID) else ()"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:variable name="catalog" select="/BMECAT/T_NEW_CATALOG/CATALOG_GROUP_SYSTEM"/>

    <xsl:variable name="referenced" as="element(CATALOG_STRUCTURE)*" select="mf:get-refs(//ARTICLE_TO_CATALOGGROUP_MAP/CATALOG_GROUP_ID)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CATALOG_STRUCTURE[some $ref in $referenced satisfies $ref is current()]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="InUse" select="'true'"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That assumes an XSLT 2.0 (or higher) processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime or Exselt.

As for how it works, the key allows us to reference the `CATALOG_STRUCTURE` elements by the `GROUP_ID`, the recursive functions then allows us to compute a sequence of all recursively referenced elements. To identify them all, the variable `referenced` selects them all, now we only need to set up a template for those elements that adds the attribute as needed, to achieve that a pattern `CATALOG_STRUCTURE[some $ref in $referenced satisfies $ref is current()]`  checks the matched node is one of the `$referenced` elements.

If you have access to an XSLT 3.0 processor like the commercial versions of Saxon 9.6 or 9.7 you can even write a pattern that simply takes the variable `referenced`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="CATALOG_STRUCTURE" use="GROUP_ID"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:get-refs" as="element(CATALOG_STRUCTURE)*">
        <xsl:param name="ids" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="refs" as="element(CATALOG_STRUCTURE)*" select="key('ref', $ids, $catalog)"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$refs, if (exists($refs)) then mf:get-refs($refs/PARENT_ID) else ()"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:variable name="catalog" select="/BMECAT/T_NEW_CATALOG/CATALOG_GROUP_SYSTEM"/>

    <xsl:variable name="referenced" as="element(CATALOG_STRUCTURE)*" select="mf:get-refs(//ARTICLE_TO_CATALOGGROUP_MAP/CATALOG_GROUP_ID)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="$referenced">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="InUse" select="'true'"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have no idead how and why it does, but it works. Will spend the rest of my day trying to undestand this. Thanks so much!

Comment: @FlorianPeschka, I have written some explanation and have added a simplified XSLT 3.0 stylesheet.